# Условие повторяемости цикла

Tags: c#, исключения, vknet

Цикл принимает пользовательский ввод в строку и парсит его, в случае неудачного парсинга или запроса на сервер по ScreenName - возвращает Эксепшн.
Какое условие можно поставить циклу, чтобы он повторялся, пока пользователь не введет корректное значение и метод не вернет корректный ответ?

```
int? numberId;
while (true)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите Id, либо ScreenName группы");
            var enterId = Console.ReadLine();
            numberId = taskLogic.IdTreatment(enterId);
                if(numberId != null)
                    break;
            }

public int? IdTreatment(string enterId)
    {

        if (int.TryParse(enterId, out int numberId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id принят успешно");
            return (int?)numberId;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Обнаружен ScreenName");
            numberId = (int)api.Utils.ResolveScreenName(enterId).Id.Value;
            return (int?)numberId;

        }

    }
```

Comment: А чем вас ваше ```if(numberId == null)``` не устраивает? Если нужно обработать Exception, то try-catch с возвратом null. Это очень плохая практика, не нужно строить логику работы программы на исключениях. Но если выбора у вас нет, то чем вам этот вариант не подходит?

Comment: Не подходит тем, что он не срабатывает). У меня цикл итак засунут в try\catch для обработки, чтобы программа не падала - а возвращала ошибку для понимания. Однако программа просто уходит в catch и хочет закрыться после, не возвращаясь к циклу

Comment: @LunarWhisper как-то так

Comment: Так, наверное, это потому что у вас цикл обёрнут в try-catch а вам нужен try-catch внутри цикла? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но повторюсь - это очень плохая практика - строить бизнес-логику на основе исключений.

```
int? numberId;
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите Id, либо ScreenName группы");
    var enterId = Console.ReadLine();
    numberId = taskLogic.IdTreatment(enterId);
    if(numberId != null)
        break;
}

public int? IdTreatment(string enterId)
{

    if (int.TryParse(enterId, out int numberId))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id принят успешно");
        return (int?)numberId;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Обнаружен ScreenName");
            numberId = (int)api.Utils.ResolveScreenName(enterId).Id.Value;
            return (int?)numberId;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
             return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!. Ради развития - как бы вы в теории реализовали данный повторный ввод?